# Evaluating a Multiline Code Block (after an `if`) Without Indentation

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Is it possible to make Python3 see an unindented code chunk as a code block?  If so how?**

This is more of a curiousity of how Python works.  Typically if you want to run a code chunk after an `if` statement you need to indent what comes below:

```
if True:
    x = 'hello'
    print(x)

## hello
```

Is there a way to use the `if` and not indent the next 2 lines?

You can get it to work if the next line is a function call (not an assignment) and you wrap it with parenthesis as seen below:

```
if True:(
print('hello')
)

## hello
```

But it fails to work if you add in multiple lines or an assignment:

```
if True:(
print('hello')
print('hello2')
)

##   File "<stdin>", line 3
##     print('hello2')
##     ^
## SyntaxError: invalid syntax
## >>> )
##   File "<stdin>", line 1
##     )
##     ^
## SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

```
if True:(
x = 'hello'
)

##   File "<stdin>", line 2
##     x = 'hello'
##       ^
## SyntaxError: invalid syntax
## >>> )
##   File "<stdin>", line 1
##     )
##     ^
## SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

Is there a way to evaluate the multiple lines after the `if` without indenting them?  Perhaps similar to the parenthisis trick I used for the simple `print('hello)` but that works for multiple lines and assignments?

Comment: Python basically WORKS with indentation, that's the basis, so no.

Answer (score 3):

This code should work:

```py
if True:(
x:='hello_x',
print('hello'),
print(x)
)

## hello
## hello_x
```

In your case, you are using a `tuple` to break python's indentation logic, so you need to separate each element with a comma. And since you are in a `tuple`, you need to use the [Walrus Operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#:%7E:text=known%20as%20%E2%80%9Cthe-,walrus,-operator%E2%80%9D.%20The%20construct%E2%80%99s) `:=` to assign a value.